# Run modular TEX files using subfiles

Tags: subfiles

I'm running into a little error here and I hope somebody can help me.

I am setting up a modular Tex document, the structure is as follows

```
|[tex]
|-environment.tex
|main.tex
|bibtex.bib
|mystyle.sty
```

with environment.tex

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
Hello World~\cite{DNV-RP-C205}.
\end{document}
```

and main.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{./mystyle}
\begin{document}
\subfile{environment}
\bibliography{bibtex} 
\end{document}
```

Running main.tex works fine, but running envorinment.tex produces the following error:

```
! LaTeX error: file ./mystyle.sty not found
```

Apperantlty, the relative location of mystyle.sty is not clear when compiling a subdocument.

However, for me this is important, to be able to run subdocuments as well instead of having to compile the complete doc every time.

Any clue on how to fix this?

Thanks!